# ORACLE-APEX : why when click on any page in the navigation menu each time its redirect first to login page?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created a dynamic menu in oracle apex but the issue when click on any page after login
to the application again it redirect to login page first then open the page

this is the URL appear when click any page in the navigation menu

```
http://localhost:8080/ords/r/apex-system/login?session=11974340821162
```

this is the SQL query for dynamic menu :

```
select level , 
EN label,
'f?p=&APP_ID.:'||menu_seq||':'||':&SESSION.:::::' target,
EN as is_current,
ICON_IMAGE image_value
from SYSTEM_MENU
start with parent_m_id is null 
connect by prior menu_id = parent_m_id 
order siblings by menu_id
```

why always go to login page when click any page link on the navigation menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the session is getting reset when navigating to a menu item. At first glance (untested) I'd say there is a syntax error in the url. The session substitution string is in the wrong place. Try replacing `':&SESSION.:::::'` with `'&SESSION.:::::'`.

But... why bother constructing the application url yourself when you can have a [function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/aeapi/GET_URL-Function.html)  `APEX_PAGE.GET_URL` do it for you ?

```
select level , 
  EN label,
  APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (p_page   => 'menu_seq') target,
  EN as is_current,
  ICON_IMAGE image_value
from SYSTEM_MENU
start with parent_m_id is null 
connect by prior menu_id = parent_m_id 
order siblings by menu_id
```

Comment: thank you so much its working and wrong extra : and I will use the function :)